# Can't print stdClass property

Tags: php, string, object

In the following example, I'm trying to print `file_already_exists` inside another string, a query, but I get this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in ...
```

```
$db_items = (object) [
    "cover" => (object) [
        "file_already_exists" => 0, // can't print
    ],
    "file_already_exists" => 0, // can print
];

$str = "INSERT INTO albums (file_on_system) VALUES ('$db_items->cover->file_already_exists')";

echo $str;
```

Using `$db_items->file_already_exists` works fine, but not `$db_items->cover->file_already_exists`. Why is that? Is there a way to print the one in `cover`?

---

In a simpler way

```
echo "$db_items->file_already_exists"; // works
echo "$db_items->cover->file_already_exists"; // doesn't work
```

Comment: Try `$db_item[0]->file_already_exists`? Not sure if it would work with objects as it's used to get first item in an array... Update: Does `var_dump($db_item->cover)` return something?

Comment: Nope. It won't allow me to treat `$db_items` as an array. `var_dump()` retuns `object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["file_already_exists"]=>
  int(0)
}`

Comment: You're getting too complex in the double quoted string. PHP will allow one `->` but not more than one unless you enclose the whole thing in `{}` `'{$db_items->cover->file_already_exists}'`.  Check examples in the manual for double quoted strings. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double.  I would always recommend enclosing anything more than simple variables in `{}`.

Comment: your are mixing up arrays and objects

Comment: @user3791775 No, the two arrays are being cast to objects, resulting in a stdClass nested inside another stdClass.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski should make this an answer!

Comment: @Jeff No need, CBroe already has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "INSERT INTO [...] VALUES ('$db_items->cover->file_already_exists')";
```

The parser does not know where the variable name ends, so it tries to insert `$db_items` into the string - and that causes the conversion issue.

Either use string concatenation

```
$str = "INSERT INTO albums [...] VALUES ('".$db_items->cover->file_already_exists."')";
```

or the [complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex),

```
$str = "INSERT INTO albums [...] VALUES ('{$db_items->cover->file_already_exists}')";
```

---

*Depending on where that value originates, do not neglect SQL injection!*

Comment: Haha. I was just thinking about how I'll deal with SQL injection. I'm quite new to SQL. It's gonna take some research.